# Select distinct on value must appear in group by

Tags: postgresql

I am encountering an error when trying to run the below query: "column "v.visit_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function."

My question is that I believe that I am already using this column in an aggregate function on line 2 `count(v.visit_id) as total_visits`. Does this not count as satisfying the error? I can't add to the GROUP BY directly since that would mess up my output.

My end goal is to select distinct visit IDs while also only grouping the output by physician names.

```
select distinct on (v.visit_id)
count(v.visit_id) as total_visits,
sum(mad2.nsma1_ans::time - mad.nsma1_ans::time) as or_hours_utilized,
sum(esla1_bt_end[1] - esla1_bt_beg[1]) as total_block_hours,
sum(extract(epoch from mad2.nsma1_ans::time) - extract(epoch from mad.nsma1_ans::time)) /
(sum(extract(epoch from esla1_bt_end[1])) - sum(extract(epoch from esla1_bt_beg[1]))) * 100 as or_percentage,
pt1.phys1_name as surgeon
from visit as v
inner join pat_phy_relation_table as pprt 
    on pprt.patphys_pat_num = v.visit_id
    and pprt.patphys_rel_type = 'ATTENDING' 
inner join physician_table1 as pt1
    on pt1.phys1_num = pprt.patphys_phy_num
    and pt1.phys1_arid = v.visit_arid --need to confirm how to handle ARIDs
inner join ews_location_table2 elt2
    on lpad(pt1.phys1_num::varchar, 6, '0') = any (elt2.esla1_bt_surg) 
    and esla1_loca in ('OR1','OR2','OR3','OR4') 
    and esla1_date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30'
    and esla1_seid = pt1.phys1_arid
inner join multi_app_documentation mad2 
    on mad2.nsma1_patnum = v.visit_id
    and mad2.nsma1_code = 'OROUT' --only pulling visits/physicians with an OROUT    
    and mad2.nsma1_ans !~ '[x,X,C,END,S]' --removing non-standard data
    and mad2.nsma1_ans != '' and mad2.nsma1_ans != '0' and mad2.nsma1_ans != '1' and mad2.nsma1_ans != '0000'
inner join multi_app_documentation mad 
    on mad.nsma1_patnum = v.visit_id
    and mad.nsma1_code = 'ORINTIME' --only pulling visits/physicians with an ORINTIME
where v.visit_admit_date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30'
and v.visit_arid = 5
group by pt1.phys1_name
```

Comment: If table descriptions would help I can also provide those.

Comment: Ideally DDL should be included in questions or at least table descriptions so that people trying to help can just paste the ddl into a test environment. Also sample data, and expected output

Comment: Also for a very complex query such as this, if you can simplify it to just the part that is causing the error, that makes it so the amount of data you need to supply is reduced and the less we have to understand about your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `distinct on (v.visit_id)` is not an aggregate function. You'd need to add it to the `group by`.

```
select
  distinct on (v.visit_id)
  count(v.visit_id) as total_visits,
...
group by v.visit_id, pt1.phys1_name
```

However, it makes no sense to use `distinct` on something you're grouping by. The group by will already only show one row for each visit_id.

```
select
  v.visit_id,
  count(v.visit_id) as total_visits,
...
group by v.visit_id, pt1.phys1_name
```

If `v.visit_id` is a primary key or unique this also makes no sense. Each visit_id will only appear once and your count will always be 1. You probably want to leave it out entirely.

```
select
  count(v.visit_id) as total_visits
...
group by pt1.phys1_name
```